# Which a better way to print in asp.net vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to print a gridview and a labels in header and label in footer ( after the gridview populated )
to use CrystalReports  or window.print
or anything else that make my goal achived ( specialy something that easy to use )

Comment: My experience tells me to use Crystal.

Comment: How about grid-to-spreadsheet. I think there are easy libraries to do this

Comment: You could use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to style the appropriate HTML elements for print.

Comment: me also thinking of Crystal Ricardo Rodrigues and aware if i face a lot of problem like manipulating html and css and and some labels and tables

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to export the datagrid, download and print from Excel.

```
Dim dg As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid 'For example if your grid was called dg
Dim reportTitle As String = "Add A Title - Since DataGrid Doesn't Have One"
'export to excel
context.Response.Buffer = True
context.Response.ClearContent()
context.Response.ClearHeaders()
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
EnableViewState = True
Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter()
Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
dg.RenderControl(hw)  '<-- built-in Method of all System.Web.UI.Control objects
Context.Response.Write("<b><center><font size=3 face=Verdana color=#0000FF>" & reportTitle & "</font></center></b>")
Context.Response.Write(tw.ToString())
Context.Response.Flush()
Context.Response.Close()
Context.Response.End()
```

For more info, you can check the Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.rendercontrol

Comment: its for client side he has no idea how to do that i want to make it easy for him

Comment: You (or another programmer) need to add a "Download" button to ths form. In the button event-handler (server-side) run this code. It will download the grid as an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: thank you for your help and my idea goes for printing not for excel

Comment: Yes, I know you want printing. Excel does printing exactly the way you asked.  And it is easy for your user, like you asked.